# .Net 8 - How many cores does it detects on Kubernetes?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, kubernetes

I was reading [this fine article about DATAS](https://www.thinktecture.com/en/net/optimize-asp-net-core-memory-with-datas/) and came across with `how many logical CPU cores can your ASP.NET Core app access?` and another question poped into my head:

- When we are talking about Kubernetes, what is the correct answer?
  The number of the "Requests"? The number of the "Limits"? What if those number are fractional and smaller than 1? Or perhaps it's the number of cores available at the node?